# Router settings for maximum speed

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

When connected to the ethernet, I get a full 100 MBPS connection.

[image]

However, through the Wifi, I end up getting 70 MBPS and it seems like the speed decreases when I am away from the router, even more.

[image]

I have an ASUS RT N66U router that is configured as follows:

- Dual band (20/40 MHz wide auto chosen) and I connect to the 2.4 GHz band while I have another SSID of 5 GHz band.
- Wireless mode - Auto (between N only and legacy)

Any quick tests and wins I can make in my configuration, to get full bandwidth through the router?

Comment: It's worth noting that in your second test you're connected to a different server and apparently have a different IP address, which could be adding other variables in. What proximity are you from the wireless point? Is there anything between you and the router, and is there any appliance near that could be causing any major interference (Microwaves, washing machines etc)? Could you confirm your wireless adapter make and model also?

Comment: http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Asus_RT-N66U also you could do some more tweaking if you don't already have ddwrt on it

Comment: What WiFi adapter does your computer have? What protocols and speeds does it support? This is pretty typical for 802.11n on 2.4GHz.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because packets sent wirelessly are more likely to arrive corrupted, so your computer asks the router to send those packets again, and that decreases your speed. The faster your connection is, more pockets will be lost in the way because more are sent.

I cannot recommend any specific settings/configuration that will increase your speed, because it depends on too much things, so it will be hard for me to tell without understanding the whole network setup.

But these basic tips should help:

1. Use 5Ghz, there are many reasons and opinions about this one, but generally, less devices use this band, so the signal should be "cleaner".
   But it weaker than 2.4GHz, so you will need to be closer to the router.
2. If you watch alot of videos or sound you may wanna try to switch on "WMM"(Wifi Multimedia), which wont increase the speed of the connection, but it will give priority to multimedia files. so it may appear faster some times.
3. If you have "XPress™ Technology" in your router settings you may wanna try to turn it on and check if it improves the seed in your case. Some say it works while other says it doesn't. if you have it, try it.
4. If you have any "Power Efficient" mode, or something similar, turn it off.

That is all i got, i hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

> When connected to wired ethernet, I get a full 100 Mbps connection.

Ok, that is normal. Wired Ethernet is usually 10, 100 or 1000 Mbps and you either get that speed or no connection at all.

> through Wifi I end up getting 70 Mbps 
>   and it seems like the speed decreases when I am away from the router

This is also normal. Wireless speeds decrease when you are further away from the access point.  Most of the time you will only approach the advertised speeds is you are right next to the access point and if no one else is using the wireless channels.  (Wireless is a shared medium. Two users at the same time actually using it will both get up to half speed).

When you move away from the wireless access point the signal strength will decrease and the number of errors will increase. WAPs work around this by dropping the speed (think about it as trying to talk slowly and clearly).

So yes. Fully normal. If you want a really fast (and low latency) connection then use wired Ethernet, not Wi-Fi.